# How to deploy a website using .ejs on hosting services?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to deploy a website using .ejs. The important thing is that the .ejs file is the "html" of the page (index.ejs).

This is a [video demo](https://imgur.com/a/VVt6JlY) of the site. As you can see everything works correctly on localhost but on github, netlify, cloudflare, etc. the page/client never loads. Does anyone know if I have to change the build deploy or something?

[image: Cloudflare build view]

Here's the source: https://github.com/johandemierda/johans

Comment: What is meant by page/client never loads. Any error messages?

Comment: No errors, the page is supposed to load once npm start is finished, when I enter the page in localhost if it loads (watch the video)

Comment: Do you own the domain `johhan.fun`?

Comment: yeah, it's mine